# Linux's system calls for GUI?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I'm studying Operating Systems. I read Window have lots of system calls for manage windows and GUI components. I have read you can change the GUI manager of your Linux Operating System. Then does Linux have system calls for GUI managements? How GUI works in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I'll take x86 as an example as I am more aware of x86 stuff than ARM stuff. Also, I may get some information wrong as I've been doing some research on this question while answering. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

**System booting**

Some time ago, Linux used to boot with a legacy bootloader (GRUB legacy version). The GRUB bootloader would be started by the BIOS at 0x7c00 in RAM and then would read the kernel from the hard-disk. It would follow the multiboot specification. The multiboot specification mentions the state that the computer needs to be in before jumping to the kernel's entry point. The kernel would then launch a first process (init) that every process would be a child of.

Today, most Linux distributions boot with UEFI (with the option of legacy booting also available). A UEFI app is placed on the boot partition partionned as a GPT ESP (EFI System Partition). This EFI app is launched and then follows the Linux Boot Protocol to launch Linux. The init process was also replaced by systemd. Linux will thus launch systemd as the first process of the computer. Actually, as stated on the manpage for systemd:

> systemd is usually not invoked directly by the user, but is
> installed as the /sbin/init symlink and started during early
> boot.

The process that will be started is thus /sbin/init but it is a symlink to systemd. The systemd process will then read several configuration files on the hard-disk called `units`. These units are often targets which specify several units to read. Targets are thus units which specify several units to read. At first systemd will read default.target which specifies several other units. Some of these other units will start some processes among which is the **Display Manager** (fancy terminology which means login prompt). Recently, Ubuntu starts the Gnome Display Manager (GDM) as the first displaying program (gdm.service unit). This program will start the X server before presenting the user login screen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager).

> When the display manager runs on the user's computer, it starts the X server before presenting the user the login screen, optionally repeating when the user logs out.

Once logged in, GDM will start several other binaries responsible to let you interact with the system (the actual desktop, a binary to gather input for this desktop, etc). All of these components depend on the X server to work properly.

**The DRM**

The X server is a user program which makes extensive use of the Direct Rendering Manager (DRM) of the Linux kernel. The DRM is a system call interface which is used to interact with graphics cards. When the DRM detects a graphics card, it exposes a file like `/dev/dri/card0` which is a character device (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/drm.7.html).

> In earlier days, the kernel framework was solely used to provide raw hardware access to
> priviledged user-space processes which implement all the hardware abstraction layers. But
> more and more tasks were moved into the kernel. All these interfaces are based on ioctl(2)
> commands on the DRM character device. The libdrm library provides wrappers for these
> system-calls and many helpers to simplify the API.
>
> When a GPU is detected, the DRM system loads a driver for the detected hardware type. Each
> connected GPU is then presented to user-space via a character-device that is usually
> available as /dev/dri/card0 and can be accessed with open(2) and close(2). However, it
> still depends on the grapics driver which interfaces are available on these devices. If an
> interface is not available, the syscalls will fail with EINVAL.

The ioctl call allows to have any number of operations on the /dev/dri/card0 file since it is a general call which includes a `request` argument which is simply an unsigned long. It also takes a variable amount of arguments (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html).

The ioctl call thus allows hardware vendors (like NVIDIA, AMD, etc) to provide drivers for their cards with the general ioctl call used as a general interface between user mode and kernel mode.

**OpenGL**

There exists several 3D rendering APIs available (OpenGL, Direct3D). OpenGL is mostly a set of C headers and a convention. The convention says what a certain call should do. It is up to the hardware vendor to implement the convention for their own card. Mesa3D has been an attempt to create an open source implementation of OpenGL for certain graphics cards. It worked quite well for integrated Intel HD Graphics (since documentation is open) and AMD (since they cooperated and offered some insight into the workings of their cards), but not for NVIDIA (the Nouveau driver is mostly not working or slow).

When you program some OpenGL, you include the OpenGL headers and link with libraries provided by hardware vendors which provide the definitions of the functions in the headers. These definitions make use of the DRM and cooperate with the X server to show content on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm studying Operating Systems. I read Window have lots of system calls for manage windows and GUI components. I have read you can change the GUI manager of your Linux Operating System. Then does Linux have system calls for GUI managements? How GUI works in Linux?

System calls (provided by the kernel) are often buried (e.g. in some cases deliberately undocumented and proprietary) and should not be used. Almost everything you see are actually normal functions in dynamically linked libraries/shared libraries. This allows the kernel's system calls to be radically changed without breaking everything (because everything only depends on the dynamically linked libraries/shared libraries); and reduces the functionality needed in the kernel itself.

For an example; most of the "system calls for managing windows and GUI components" you think Windows has could (internally, inside the relevant DLL) just end up using a single "send_message()" system call (to tell a different process, the GUI, that you want to create a window or change its position or ...).

For Linux it's roughly similar. The kernel's system calls (which actually are documented, for no sane reason - it goes against the spirit of SYS-V specs and means badly written "linux executables" aren't compatible with other Unix clones like FreeBSD or Solaris or OSX) exist to use things like low level memory management and raw file IO and sockets; but (like Windows) the kernel's system calls are buried under layers of shared libraries, and those shared libraries (e.g. like Xlib, GLib, KWindowSystem, Qt, ...) just use "something" (file IO, pipes, sockets, ...) provided by kernel to talk to another process (display server, GUI, ..).

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Windows fall under separate categories; Linux is just a kernel, i.e. the piece under the hood that gives us the basic functionality we expect to run programs, like threads, memory and process management, etc. Windows is a full operating system, including the user facing components and numerous system libraries. An apter comparison would be a specific Linux distro and Windows.

On that note, distros, as independent operating systems, obviously can have different implementations of any OS component. Some distros, like Arch, don't come with a GUI by default at all. That said, essentially the entire Linux ecosystem uses Xorg and/or Wayland; I would recommend looking into the implementation details of those two.

Answer (score 0):

A Linux GUI has quite a few differences compared to Windows GUI. For example, the GUI is not considered to be a part of the operating system, but rather an external part of it; that means no syscalls (not embedded whatsoever in the OS). After all, like the previous answer says, Linux is a **kernel**, that means it's only something really basic (allows execution of programs, memory/threads management, processes management, but not really much more). Whatever comes next (GUI, for example) are added features using packages.
This allows, for example, installing a GUI on top of a minimal installation of any Linux distro (CentOS, for example), and that GUI can be the one you want (Gnome, KDE...).

Comment: For an idea of how a graphics implementation would happen, someone added simple graphics to MIT's simplified, older (x86-based) OS: https://github.com/evangutman/Double-Buffered-Graphics-in-xv6/blob/master/xv6-public/graphics.c (Note, they did make custom syscalls which directly access known memory addresses via inline assembly.)